# Add dynamic button with onclick functionality to cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to dynamically add a button with an onclick functionality to my table's cell but i seem to have a problem with my formatting.

My JS:

```
noteArrHelper = noteArr[i];
console.log(noteArrHelper);
cell2.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\""+"onclick=deleteNote(\""+noteArrHelper+"\")"+">Delete";
cell2.className = "noteright";
```

And this is how it looks like in the browser:

```
<button type="button" "onclick="deleteNote("joyful="" test")"="">Delete</button>
```

But i want it to look like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteNote("joyful test")">Delete</button>
```

I tried a few other ways of formatting but couldn't get it to work. Also the browser puts out the "joyful test" part correctly without any "=" between the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by simply changing third line in your JS code to the following:

```
cell2.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"deleteNote('"+noteArrHelper+"')\">Delete</button>";
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Live Demo:**

```js
//var
let noteArrHelper = 'joyful test'
//innerHTML
document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = `<button type="button" onclick="deleteNote('${noteArrHelper}')">Delete</button>`;

   //function
function deleteNote(str) {
  console.log(str) //joyful test
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use Template literals

```
cell2.innerHTML = `<button type="button" onclick=${deleteNote(noteArrHelper)} >Delete</button>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mate

```
cell2.innerHTML = "<button type='button' onclick=\"deleteNote(\'" + noteArrHelper + "\')\">Delete</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to use quotes multiple time, then use single quotes and double quotes in your code

```
cell2.innerHTML = "<button type='button'onclick='deleteNote('+noteArrHelper+')'>Delete</button>";
```